# Sync Ajax calls in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I want to test server for a given value and return calculation based on that, but I don't know how to make sync calls in Angular/TS/JS.

For example I want the following function return an integer value, xhr is called inside the function, I need to wait for response and return calculations based on that.

```
function check()
{
    var value = this.http.get('/check').waitUntilProcessed().returnResponseValue();
    return value > 0 ? 'a' : 'b';
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only way I've found to do this is using ajax with `async:false` but I really really _really_ advise against using that in all but one situation, `onbeforeunload`.  What you need here is a better understanding of promises, observables, and callback functions.

Comment: Stop learning Angular for a bit and go learn the fundamentals of RxJs, Angular is built upon RxJs and if you don't have the fundamentals down you will write very different code than if you got on top of observables first. Reactive programming is one of the best innovations in UI development in many years but takes a bit of time to grasp the fundamentals. Your Angular code will be of vastly greater quality if you put the time into RxJs before starting your Angular journey.

Comment: @AdrianBrand, Thank you Adrian for the advise, I'm server side developer but I have to change modify an Angular UI for the project. But I'm falling in love with it. I make sure to learn about RxJS as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous XHR requests are now deprecated. So while you can still use them, you'll get warnings all over the place.

The correct answer is to rewrite your code so that the http client utilizes Promises and async/await. So while your code will still be asynchronous, it could look something like this:

```
async function check {
  var value = await this.http.get('/check').returnResponseValue()
  return value > 0 ? 'a' : 'b'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks acceptable to solve my problem. Could you also tell more about how to implement returnResponseValue()? Or how to populate `value` to preparing the result? Doesn't angular have such feature already? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the map pipe on the http request to have an observable that emits your value

```
value$ = this.http.get('/check').pipe(map(value => value > 0 ? 'a' : 'b'));
```

and in the template use the async pipe

```
{{ value$ | async }}
```

Or assign it to a view variable to use it

```
<ng-container *ngIf="value$ | async as value else loading">
  <div *ngIf="value === 'a'">Check was greater than 0</div>
  <div *ngIf="value === 'b'">Check was not greater than 0</div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>
  ...loading
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian for taking time to answer. I'll check it out later and come back to you if it didn't solved the question. Thanks again.